# What is correct parameter type to use that accept tuples in swift?

Tags: swift

I am writing a function that accepts an array of anything:

```
 func getRandomMember(from:[Any]) {
```

But when I pass it an array of tuples:

```
 getRandomMember([(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1, -1)])
```

Xcode tells me it is an error:

```
[(Int, Int)] is not convertable to [Any].
```

`AnyObject` doesn't work either. So what type should I use as the parameter type?

Comment: You should probably use Swift generics for this?

Comment: If you are using `Any`, you are doing it wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I test your code in a playground, it works perfectly fine. I think you just forgot to add the argument label `from`.

```
getRandomMember(from: [(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1, -1)])
```

However, although the above works, I think using generics here is a better choice here. You can declare your function generically:

```
func getRandomMemeber<T>(from array: [T]) -> T
```

This way, you don't need to cast the value returned to the type you want.

Comment: No, I didn't forget to add `from` in my code. That's strange, perhaps related to swift version? Anyway, generics works fine. Thanks!